# Limit (Stationary) distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes

Suppose I have linear stochastic process
$$ x_{k+1} = a x_{k} + w_{k} \quad \text{with} \quad x_0 = x.$$
Here $0 < a < 1 $ and $\{w_{k}\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables.

I am wondering if there are results for the limit or stationary distribution
of the process, i.e., the probability distribution of $x_{\infty} = \lim_{k\to\infty}x_k$. Of course if one takes $w_k$ to be Gaussian, $x_{\infty}$ will be Gaussian too. But, I'm looking for something like uniform/beta/sub-exponential $w_{k}$ and preferably something that can be constructed explicitly.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why should $(x_k)$ have any limit at all?  I believe you are looking for a limit of the *distributions,* not the random variables.

Comment: if $a<1$ wouldn't $x_k$ converge to some limit too? But yes, in general I am looking at the limit of the distributions.

Comment: While $x_k$ itself may not converge to any well-known distribution, $\bar{x}_k = \frac{1}{k}(x_1 + \cdots + x_k)$ is asymptotically normal.  See Theorem 7.1.2 of *Time Series: Theory and Methods*.

Comment: @Zhanxiong This is something that intuitively I do not understand. Again suppose each $x_i$ has bounded support, $\overline{x}_{k}$ must have bounded support too, right?

Comment: @NoobNoob You mean you do not understand why $\bar{x}_k$ is asymptotically normal or what else? Your second question is not contradictive with what I said.  By "asymptotically normal", I mean, by convention, the standardized sample mean **multiplied with square root of  $n$** (as opposed to the sample mean itself), converges to $N(0, 1)$.

Comment: Suppose the common distribution of the $w_k$ is bounded: that is, there is some number $M$ for which $\Pr(|w_k|\gt M) = 0$ for all $k.$  Then it is clear all the $x_k$ are bounded.  Moreover, supposing $x_k$ is bounded by some value $M_k,$ almost surely $|x_{k+1}| \le |ax_k+w_{k+1}| \le |a||x_k|+|w_{k+1}|\le aM_k+M.$ This inductively implies $M_k\le M/(1-a),$ showing if $(x_k)$ has a limit, it must be bounded -- and thus certainly is not Normal!

Comment: Thanks @whuber, this was clear to me. Still, I havent managed to say more about the stationary distributions. I know the transient distributions are piecewise polynomials of $k$-th order (in case the common distributions are uniform, for example). But more than that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can apply the CLT?

Assume $x_0=0$. Then we have $x_k=\sum_{i=1}^k \alpha^{i-1}w_i$.

If $Var(w_i)=\sigma^2 < \infty \, \forall i$, we have for $Y_i := \alpha^{i-1}w_k$:

$Var(Y_i)=\alpha^{2i-2}\sigma^2$.

If you could proof that the Lindeberg Condition
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) holds in this case, you could I apply the CLT and get the distribution of $x_k$ converges to a gaussian distribution.

Comment: Consider the case where infinitely many of the $w_k$ do not have Normal distributions: should the limiting distribution, if it exists, be Normal?

Comment: I am more interested in the case where the CLT does not apply. Take for example each $w_k$ to be uniform. Also interested in the case where $x_0$ is not a dirac random variable but actually uniform too. In each of those cases you can not possibly have gaussian limiting distribution.